# How do I find out where login scripts live?

Tags: active-directory

I am looking for a way (manual or progamatic) to find out where the user's activer directory login script is located.

I can parse the results of "net user" to get the script name, but that doesn't tell me what file share the script lives on.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In addition from the command prompt run SET.

This displayed the "LOGONSERVER" value which indicates the specific domain controller you are using (there can be more than one).

Then you got to that server's NetBios Share \Servername\SYSVOL\domain.local\scripts.

Comment: If you don't like searching in the list you get from `SET`, like I did, you can use `echo %LOGONSERVER%`

Comment: You can also type `%LOGONSERVER%\SYSVOL` directly in the addressbar of Windows Explorer.

Comment: These seem easier than my usual scan for `*.bat`

Answer (score 6):

The default location for logon scripts is the netlogon share of a domain controller. On the server this is located:

%SystemRoot%'SYSVOL'sysvol''scripts

It can presumably be changes from this default but I've never met anyone that had a reason to.

To get list of domain controllers programatically see this article:
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/dec04/hey1216.mspx

Comment: Well then my followup question is how do I determine my domain controller.

Comment: The above %systemroot% path looks malformed, no? Isn't it supposed to be `%systemroot%\SYSVOL\sysvol\scripts`, or similar (I notice most information I have found so far only has one level deep of `sysvol` directories)?